Section numbering stops working but intendation exists
I am pretty new to Latex and Overleaf, which I am trying to use for my dissertation.
I have made some progress, but I am stuck with section number. As indicated in the title, section numbering looks like it does not work properly, and only an indentation is added - which is also then displayed on the toc.


My code is split in 3, the main page, the preface page and the main body page, where the section is.
main
\documentclass[12pt, 
               a4paper,  
               openright,
               oneside]{article}
   

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage} 
\pagestyle{empty}

{\LARGE \textbf{\theTitle}} \\
\vspace{5mm}\hrule\vspace{5mm}  

\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
\end{titlepage}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\input{Prequel}
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}


\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}  
\setcounter{section}{1}



\input{Introduction}
\clearpage



\end{document}

Preface
\section*{Preface and Acknowledgments}
\markboth{PREFACE AND ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\label{preface}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}


\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\topskip0pt

\centerline{\footnotesize (This page was intentionally left blank)}

\newpage

\section*{Abstract\markboth{ABSTRACT}}
\label{abstract}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}


\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\topskip0pt

\centerline{\footnotesize (This page was intentionally left blank)}


\newpage


\rhead{\rightmark} 
\lhead{}
\tableofcontents
\label{contents}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}

\clearpage


\listoffigures
\label{figures}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\clearpage

\listoftables
\markboth{LIST OF TABLES}
\label{tables}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\clearpage
    

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\printacronyms[name=List of Abbreviations, pages={display=all}]
\markright{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\label{abbr}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\clearpage

\printglossary[title=Glossary of Terms]
\label{gloss}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}

Introduction
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please minimalize your given code -- as usual here -- to be short, compilable and resulting in your issue!

Thanks @Mensch, I believe it is now reduced as much as possible without affecting a possible solution

@Svestis Do you really need a special font to reproduce the problem? Do you really need local images, which we don't have, to reproduce the problem? etc.

It is also unlikely you need to have files inputted in order to generate your problem.

Too lazy to try to compile your code fragments, but \renewcommand{\thesection}{} might not be the best of ideas...

Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and daleif for your patience. Removed raw content, local files and left only configuration issues.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and that was exactly the issue, thanks! Do you want to post it as an answer and I will accept it?

@Svestis Feel free to post a self-answer if you'd like.

With many thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, the usage of \renewcommand{\thesection}{} was affecting the section numbering display. Removing this command from the preface part of the code resolved the issue and now numbering is displayed correctly


